# What circuit will output a short latch pulse when the clock input pauses?

Tags: clock, shift-register

I'm transmitting serial data across a cable to a shift register. I transmit data in discrete packets, where different packets have different bit lengths. The clock frequency is about 20 MHz while transmitting.

When each packet ends, I need to generate a short pulse to latch the shift register. I know a packet has ended when the clock stays low for a few cycles.

What circuit will output this latch signal?

[image: Timing chart example]

Commenters asked some good questions about timing, so I'll clarify:

- The shortest packet is 800 bits, for a duration of 40 μs minimum.
- Idle time between packets is 10 μs minimum.
- The latch pulse duration must be 10 nanoseconds minimum.

Comment: 1) Is the clock rate known, or at least constrained?

Comment: 2) Do you need a fully synchronous solution, or would an analog hack (using a 555 timer, for example) be OK?

Comment: 3) Do you need a pulse, or would just a rising or falling edge suffice?

Comment: a re-triggerable monostable multivibrator (retrig one-shot) would be the kind of circuit that you are looking for

Comment: @jsotola I upped your comment. But I think it may require two of them. 74123.

Comment: @jonk, a second one-shot may be required ... depends on the latch circuit requirement

Comment: 1st you must be more specific.  T1= Duration free of clock transitions ,T2 for duration of pulse and recurring if necessary. With tolerances.. even if you don’t care....

Comment: Your clock is a long low. A "one shot" triggered by a long low and reset by a high would do this.

Comment: you want a missing pulse detector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters , I've come up with a solution: invert the intermittent clock signal, pass that to a [missing pulse detector](https://www.electronicshub.org/monostable-multivibrator-using-555-timer/#Missing_Pulse_Detector), and pass that output to a [falling-edge pulse detector](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/edge-triggered-latches-flip-flops/).

[Here's a simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+1.5625e-9+0.1086904049521229+56+5+50%0A165+336+176+448+176+4+0%0Aw+336+208+336+304+0%0Aw+336+208+304+208+0%0Aw+304+208+304+304+0%0Ac+304+304+304+368+0+1.0000000000000002e-10+0.04950495049505939%0Ag+304+368+304+384+0%0Ar+304+208+304+144+0+1000%0Aw+304+144+400+144+0%0AO+736+256+768+256+0%0AR+304+144+304+96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0At+224+336+256+336+0+-1+5+4.95049504950484+100%0Aw+256+320+256+304+0%0Ar+256+304+304+304+0+100%0Aw+256+352+256+368+0%0Aw+256+368+304+368+0%0Aw+224+272+224+336+0%0AR+80+288+80+336+0+2+20000000+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0AL+80+256+80+208+0+0+false+5+0%0Aw+400+144+464+144+0%0Aw+464+144+464+208+0%0Ag+432+336+432+352+0%0Ap+480+272+480+336+1+0%0Aw+480+240+480+272+0%0Ag+480+336+480+352+0%0AI+512+272+560+272+0+0.5+5%0AI+560+272+608+272+0+0.5+5%0AI+608+272+656+272+0+0.5+5%0A153+656+256+736+256+0+2+0+5%0Aw+480+240+656+240+0%0Aw+512+272+480+272+0%0Aw+224+272+336+272+0%0A150+80+272+160+272+0+2+0+5%0AI+160+272+224+272+0+0.5+5%0Aw+464+240+480+240+0%0A207+160+272+160+176+4+intermittent%5Csclock%5Csinput%0Ao+34+1+0+4102+5+0.1+0+2+34+3%0Ao+21+1+0+4102+5+0.1+0+1%0Ao+8+1+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+1+output%0A). Click **L** or **H** to start or end a packet.

[image: circuit diagram and timing chart]